# what function can help me to know user input first character in textfield and how to make a blank line when I press keyboard return?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, textfield

I have two problems.I am a beginner of swift 
First,I want to hide the send button until user input frist character.I use textfield delegate functions that they don't implement this idea.

And then, I want to creat a blank line when user input in textfield.I know to use "textFieldShouldReturn" function ,but I use "\n" that it doesn't work for me.How to do this?

this is my code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

if textField.text?.isEmpty == false {

        aButton.isHidden = true
        sendButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

update code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.textField.text = "\n"

    return true
}
```

I also want the textfield change it height.let user can input their message. Does it can be implement?
Or I need to change textfield to textview.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859821/disable-button-until-text-fields-have-been-entered

Comment: oh it's objective c. lol

Comment: can you please post code for blank line so we can help you.

Comment: so do you want blank line whenuser done text editing ? as per your code it will make your textfiled blank but if you want to addpend new line with user's text then you need to change it like this let text = self.textField.text + "\n" and assign it to your textfied

Answer (score 1):

You can use textfields delegate method to check when user start writing something in your textfield.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField == txtUserName //compare with your textfield object which you have taken by outlet 
    {
        if string.characters.count >= 1 {
        //make your button enable
        }else
        {
        // disable  your button
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: how to validate multiple textfield