# Enable button only after text fields are entered

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, uitextfield

Apple started rejecting my app (after yrs of approvals) - I have 2 text fields for a few char of last, first name, then press Go. They claim - I can't reproduce that the app crashes if you just press Go - when I run it it tries to send the request but kicks it back with an error 'No name - please reenter'. Whatever. To appease Apple I edited my text field entry method to now (see below) - but still not working. Please advise.

```
// Text Field methods

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    
    UIFont* boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 24];
    
    if (textField == _lastName) {
        [_lastName becomeFirstResponder];
        [_lastName setFont:boldFont];
        _lastName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;;
        _lastName.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        _lastName.text = @"";
        
        NSLog(@"user editing last...");
        
        // Enable button once fields have values
            
        if ([_lastName.text isEqual: @""] && [_firstName.text  isEqual: @""])
            {
                _fwdButton.enabled = YES;
            }
        
    }
    
    else {
        [_firstName becomeFirstResponder];
        [_firstName setFont:boldFont];
        _firstName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;;
        _firstName.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        _firstName.text = @"";
        
        NSLog(@"user editing first");
        
        // Enable button once fields have values
            
        if ([_lastName.text isEqual: @""] && [_firstName.text  isEqual: @""])
            {
                _fwdButton.enabled = YES;
            }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable button until text fields have been entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859821/disable-button-until-text-fields-have-been-entered)

Answer (score -2):

I was able to add code similar to[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859821/disable-button-until-text-fields-have-been-entered][1]

to deal with the situation.